# Regex Match complex expression

Tags: regex

i've the following examples of my expressions

```
A > 16
A <= 16 and A >= 1
A < 40 or A > -40
A != 19 and A > 50 and A != 8
A > 1 or A < 2
```

can i do such evaluation in a single regex?

basicly

1. only allow the following sympols `> < = ! - != >= <=`
2. there has to be space before `and`/`or` operators and after the `A`
   only if its not the first letter.
3. my variable is always constant, which in this case is `A`

google did not help this time and i am really new to regex, a guide about how to achive such things would be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
^A ([<>!]=?|=) -?\d+( (and|or) A ([<>!]=?|=) -?\d+)*$
```

It allows for expressions where `A` is compared to some positive or negative integer using one of the comparitors `<`, `>`, `!`, `<=`, `>=`, `!=`, followed by bay any number of other similar expressions, separated by `and` or `or`—you listed `!` and `!=` as separate symbols, so I've allowed both as comparators, i.e. my solution actually allows expressions like `A ! 2`. If this is not desirable, replace `([<>!]=?|=)` with `([<>]=?|!?=)` in the above pattern.

You can test it out [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5EA%20%28%5B%3C%3E!%5D=?%7C=%29%20-?%5Cd%2b%28%20%28and%7Cor%29%20A%20%28%5B%3C%3E!%5D=?%7C=%29%20-?%5Cd%2b%29%2a%24&input=A%20%3E%2016%0AA%20%3C=%2016%20and%20A%20%3E=%201%0AA%20%3C%2040%20or%20A%20%3E%20-40%0AA%20!=%2019%20and%20A%20%3E%2050%20and%20A%20!=%208%0AA%20%3E%201%20or%20A%20%3C%202).

Here's a slightly simplified version you could try out as well:

```
^(A ([<>!]=?|=) -?\d+( (and|or) |$))+$
```